# Filtrando categorias por link en misma pagina principal, error Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

tengo una pagina principal compuesta por artículos en la que se muestran  los últimos artículos que se han recibido, y listado `(links)` de todas las categorías y el numero de artículos que tiene cada categoría. 
Lo que quiero hacer es `filtrar`, es decir que al pulsar en un `link` vaya al método de un controlador que hace referencia a una `scope` y usando las mismas variables del método del mismo controlador para mostrar la pagina principal, filtre el contenido, es decir que cada `link` que pinches salgan los artículos por esa categoría.
La idea es reutilizar el código así como las variables del controlador

Llevo un rato dándole vueltas, seguro que es una tontería pero ya no veo nada

**Este es el error**

> ErrorException in c91ad600cf0c607229837e7ba61e74098bd6634d.php line
>   20: Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\HTDOCS_PHP\Laravel_CodigoFacilito\resources\views\admin\partials\asidefront.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\HTDOCS_PHP\Laravel_CodigoFacilito\resources\views\admin\partials\asidefront.blade.php)

**Controlador Principal**

```
public function index()
    {
        $tags = \App\modelos\tag::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        $categorias = \App\modelos\categoria::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();

        $articulos = \App\modelos\articulo::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(4);  

        return View('front.index',compact('articulos','categorias','tags'));
    }

 public function buscaCategoria($nombrecat) //FUNCION PARA FILTRAR
    {

        $tags =  \App\modelos\tag::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        $categorias = \App\modelos\categoria::BuscaCategoria($nombrecat)->first();

        $articulos = $categorias->articulos()->paginate(4);
        return View('front.index',compact('articulos','categorias','tags'));

    }
```

**Vista Principal**

```
@section('contenido')


    <h3 class="title-front left">Ultimos productos</h3>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                    @foreach($articulos as $articulo)
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title text-uppercase">{{$articulo->title}}</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body" id="imagenesArticulos">
                            @foreach($articulo->imagenes as $imagenes)
                            <img src="{{url('/ima/articulos/'.$imagenes->nombre)}}">
                            @endforeach()
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non totam, assumenda reprehenderit itaque esse ea dignissimos dolorem, at nam porro repudiandae placeat et commodi reiciendis tempora dolore est aliquid, ut facere earum molestiae hic quaerat sunt magnam. Animi nobis sequi ea aliquam saepe, minima culpa nemo. Veritatis dolor reprehenderit assumenda, nihil minima commodi tenetur aliquam, obcaecati, quisquam aspernatur, laborum dolore tempore error impedit ipsa cupiditate voluptate porro cumque. Omnis adipisci, velit labore accusamus temporibus, nam quidem consequatur beatae ab pariatur porro, quisquam, culpa asperiores nisi laborum in illo voluptates libero quo reprehenderit amet corporis. Accusantium optio autem consequatur excepturi illo dolores culpa aliquid eligendi aspernatur, temporibus, sapiente amet aut possimus tempora obcaecati quasi suscipit dolore maiores hic, sit, ipsa? Corporis vitae quia quam, ipsum repellendus quo, voluptates. A, sed pariatur consectetur eveniet, natus nobis recusandae voluptatum, beatae, numquam alias distinctio vitae id incidunt facere quos illo odio eligendi similique quasi.</p>
                        <hr>
                            <h3 class="text-center">{{$articulo->title}}</h3>

                                    <a>{{$articulo->categoria->nombre}}</a>
                        <div class="pull-right">

                                <p>{{$articulo->updated_at->diffForHumans()}}</p>
                                </div>  

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>

        </div>

    @include('admin.partials.asidefront')

    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {{$articulos->appends(Request::all())->render()}}
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

**Asidefront (Include en la Vista Principal)(Aquí esta el error)**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Categorias</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="list-group">

                            @foreach($categorias as $categoria)

                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <span class="badge">{{count($categoria->articulos)}}</span>
                            <a href="{{url('buscaCat/'.$categoria->nombre)}}">{{$categoria->nombre}}</a>

                        </li>
                            @endforeach


                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>


            </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">TAGS</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body" id="etiquetas" >

                    @foreach($tags as $tag)
                    <a href="{{url('buscaTag/'.$tag->tags)}}">
                        <span class="label label-info" >{{$tag->tags}}</span>
                    </a>

                    @endforeach




                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

La pagina principal me la muestra sin problemas , esto me pasa al referenciar al método `buscaCategoria`.

¿Alguna idea?  Gracias.

********************************Añadido Primera Edición*************
Modelo Categoría

```
class categoria extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categorias';

    protected $fillable = array('nombre');


     public function articulos()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\modelos\articulo');
    }



    public function scopeBuscaCategoria($query,$nombreCat)
    {

        return $query->where('nombre', 'LIKE','%'.$nombreCat.'%');
    }
}
```

**DD de Categorías de Pagina Principal**

[image: DD DE PAGINA PRINCIPAL]

**DD de Categorías de Busca Categorías**

[image: DD DE CATEGORIAS DE BUSCA CATEGORIAS]

La linea 20 en teoria es el count de estas linea en el fichero aside

```
                    @foreach($categorias as $categoria)

                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <span class="badge">{{count($categoria->articulos)}}</span>
                        <a href="{{url('buscaCat/'.$categoria->nombre)}}">{{$categoria->nombre}}</a>

                    </li>
                        @endforeach
```

*************************Añadido Segunda Edición****************************

**Modelo Artículos**

```
<?php


class articulo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'articulos';

    protected  $fillable = array('title','content','categoria_id','user_id');

     public function categoria()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\modelos\categoria','categoria_id', 'id');
    }

     public function imagenes()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\modelos\imagen');
    }

          public function tags()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\modelos\tag');
    }

           public function usuario()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }


    public function scopebuscadordeArticulos($query,$buscador)
    {
       return $query->where('title','like','%'.$buscador.'%');
    }
}
```

*****************************TERCERA EDICION******SOLUCION***************
 public function buscaCategoria($nombrecat) //FUNCION PARA FILTRAR
        {

```
        $tags =  \App\modelos\tag::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
                    $categorias = \App\modelos\categoria::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();  
        $catporArticulo = \App\modelos\categoria::BuscaCategoria($nombrecat)->first();

        $articulos = $catporArticulo->articulos()->paginate(4);
        return View('front.index',compact('articulos','categorias','tags'));

    }
```

Comment: Varias preguntas: ¿Cuál es la línea 20 del error? ¿Podrías agregar (a la pregunta) el código del modelo de categoria? ¿Podrías hacer un dump() de $categorias? (para ver al menos un resultado, no todos)

Comment: Añadido todo lo que me comentas al post principal

Comment: Olvidé solicitarte el modelo de artículos, por favor.

Comment: Añadido al post principal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el controlador estás llamando el método `first()` al momento de hacer la consulta:

```
$categorias = \App\modelos\categoria::BuscaCategoria($nombrecat)->first();
```

Solo obtendrás un elemento y no una colección (tal y como se ve en el DD de $categorias) y por consiguiente al momento de contar (en la vista) nos dice que `$categoria` no es un objeto (no hay nada ahí).

```
@foreach($categorias as $categoria)
```

Las opciones que tienes son (dependiendo lo que quieras hacer en tu aplicación):

- Eliminar el método `first()` de tu consulta y reemplazarlo por `get()` u otro método.
- No hacer un foreach en la vista, no es necesario si tienes solo un objeto.

Comment: Solucionado por fin, era un error de planteamiento inicial por mi parte, gracias a tu ultima respuesta lo he visto claro, estaba enviando las categorias con el metodo first, cuando realmente esas categorias eran unicamente para hacer el filtro por articulos, necesitaba usar 2 variables para categorias una para enviarla y otra para filtrar por articulos. Pues nada Muchas gracias por el tiempo que te has tomado en ayudarme. Un saludo.